# Showing vectors span a vector space by definition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to show that the vectors $v_1 = \langle 2, 1\rangle$ and $v_2 = \langle 4, 3\rangle$ span $\mathbb R^2$ by definition. By definition if I can write any vector in $\mathbb R^2$ as a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$ then the vectors span $\mathbb R^2$. How do I show this? Here is what I have been working with:

1. Let $v_x = \langle c_1, c_2\rangle$ be any vector in $\mathbb R^2$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are in $\mathbb R$.
2. $v_x = c_1\langle 1, 0\rangle + c_2\langle 0, 1\rangle$
3. Set $v_x$ = a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$? How do I proceed from here?

Comment: $v_1=$ what? Similarly, $v_2=$ what?

Comment: I am having an error rendering the <> symbols. Any suggestions? It shows up fine when I am editing

Comment: Fixed it, thanks!

Comment: I need to explicitly show that the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ span $\mathbb R^2$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need to prove is the following:

$$\forall\,v:=(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2\,\,\,\exists\,x,y\in\Bbb R\,\,\,s.t.\,\, v=x(2,1)+y(4,3)\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \text{the linear system}\,\,\left\{\begin{array}{}2x+4y=a\\{}\\\;\;x+3y=b\end{array}\right.$$

has a solution for *any* $\,a,b\in\Bbb R\,$

Now, the above system *always* has a solution (and, in fact, a *unique one* for each choice of $\,a,b\in\Bbb R\,$) since the reduced coefficients matrix's determinant is $\,2\cdot 3-1\cdot 4=2\neq 0\,$ , and voilá.

Comment: @MichaelLevy Good for you, and good luck.

Comment: I clarify symbols of Don Antonio to English: For all vectors $v$  such that $v$ is defined to be the ordered pair $(a,b)$ and such that $v$ is an element of real-coordinate space $\mathbb{R}^2$,  there is at least one pair $x,y$, where both $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, such that $v= x\,(2,1) + y\,(4,3)$ is true. The aforementioned statement is materially equivalent to the specific system of 2 linear equations with 2 unknowns written as (i) $2\,x+4\,y=a$; and (ii) $1\,x+3\,y=b$, which has a solution for any $a,b$, which are both real numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols

Comment: @MichaelLevy Nice...you are aware of the fact, of course, that this question was answered **and accepted** by the asker more than 5.5 years ago...right?

Comment: My comment is intended to clarify your writing -- nothing more and nothing less.  Yes, I can see when the questions was asked and when it was accepted.

Answer (score 2):

We want to show that any $\mathbf{v} = (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ can be written as $v = a\mathbf{v_1}+b\mathbf{v_2}$. This equation can be written more explicitly like this: $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix} = a\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix}4 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$, because $\mathbf{v_1} = \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{v_2} = \begin{pmatrix}4 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$. We'd like to show that no matter what $(x,y)$ is, there always are $a,b$ that satisfy the above equation.

So let's do that. This equation is a vector equation, so it is really two equations. We can separate it:

$$
\begin{align}
2a+4b &= x \\
a+3b &= y \end{align}
$$

Remember that the unknowns here are $a$ and $b$. $x$ and $y$ can be anything; in fact we want to show that no matter what $x$ and $y$ are, there are $a$ and $b$ that satisfy these equations. If we say $A = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 4 \\ 1 & 3\end{pmatrix},\ \mathbf{w} = \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \end{pmatrix},\ \mathbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$. This system of equations can be written more succintly as $A\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{x}$. Again, remember that the unknown is $\mathbf{w}$, not $\mathbf{x}$.

We know that this system has a solution $\mathbf{w}$ for every $\mathbf{x}$ if and only if $\det(A) \neq 0$. If we can show that, we have shown that no matter which $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ we pick, there are $a,b$ such that $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix} = a\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix}4 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$. I leave this calculation to you.

Comment: I need to only use the definition of Span.

Comment: This indeed uses only the defintion. I'll edit to make it more explicit.

Comment: The above answer, and also mine, *use* the definition of span, but you need to show a solution exists and for this nothing as clear, simple and basic as linear equations...what else?!

Answer (score 2):

If you can prove that $\langle 1,0\rangle$ and $\langle 0,1\rangle$ can be written as linear combinations of $v_1$ and $v_2$, and then combine that fact with statements 1 and 2, that would be enough.

In general, if you can show that all elements of one known basis can be written as linear combinations of a set of linearly independent vectors, then it follows that the aforementioned set is also a basis.

Answer (score 1):

Well, suppose $e_1=\langle 1,0\rangle$ and $e_2=\langle 0,1\rangle$--that is, $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is the standard ordered basis for $\Bbb R^2$. It's readily seen that $e_2=v_2-2v_1$, and that $e_1=\frac12(v_1-e_2)=\frac12(3v_1-v_2)$. At that point, you can write every vector in $\Bbb R^2$ uniquely as a linear combination of $v_1,v_2$, pretty much exactly as you described.